# IBM Bluemix Watson IOT - How to be notified of service updates

Tags: ibm-cloud, watson-iot

Last week, we noticed a lack of incoming data on our Waston IOT platform.
After some research, we found that the HTTP API of Watson has moved to a new url (only the part to publish messages).

The official documentation is effectively mentionning the new url and we found just one post on the web talking about this update ([here](https://developer.ibm.com/iotplatform/2016/10/17/http-api-changes/)). Moreover, this post does not provide precise dates.
We checked our mails for the last 5 months, we were never notified in advance of this update. It's really problematic for us since we provide business apps to customers based on this service.

So the question is : Did the watson team failed to notify us or is there another way than emails to take notice of the schedule of future updates?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this point we do not directly email customers.  We have been exploring options of ways to do this and hope to have a procedure in place to notify customers of any changes to the Watson IoT platform in the very near future.  We apologize for any inconvenience this change caused.